# SSL: can't load CA certificate file /Users/xxxxx/goagent/local/CA.crt

Tags: github, ssl-certificate, cocoapods, gemspecs

```
server:~ Wanglichen$ pod setup
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:127: 
    warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
[!] The signature of CLAide#arguments has changed. 
    Use CLAide::Argument (Pod::Command::CheckLatest: `[["NAME", :required]]`)

Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth\=1

Cloning into 'master'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': 
    SSL: can't load CA certificate file /Users/Wanglichen/goagent/local/CA.crt

server:~ Wanglichen$
```